# How do i use tooltip on ngb pagination first page icon in angular

Tags: angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap

i need to apply tool tip on the ngb pagination but have no idea what to use for it i used google but found no results.

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]='paginationTotalPages' [maxSize]="5" [pageSize]="1" [(page)]="paginationCurrentPage"
              (pageChange)="paginationCheck()" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true" [ellipses]="false"></ngb-pagination>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Add below three,

**data-toggle="tooltip"**

**data-placement="top"**

**title="page no"**

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]='paginationTotalPages' [maxSize]="5" [pageSize]="1" [(page)]="paginationCurrentPage"
          (pageChange)="paginationCheck()" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true" [ellipses]="false" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="page no" ></ngb-pagination>
```